# Refrigerator cools once but then doesn't start up again

Tags: refrigerator, cooling

We have a Whirlpool Side by Side refrigerator (GS6SHAXML00) that is about 15 years old and was working fine before a long-distance move. When we got to the new house and plugged it in, it seemed to work fine -- it came on, both the refrigerator and freezer got to the appropriate temperature, and it cycled off. The problem is that it never came back on again. If we unplug it and plug it back in, it goes through the same cycle. It would be usable if we wanted to unplug it after every time it shuts off... (not). Can anyone tell me if there might be an easy fix for this or should we just get a new one (after the move, not a lot in the budget for that)? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; let's see if you get any good answers. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Did you tilt it significantly while moving, and did you lay it on its side at any point?  How much time elapsed between the tilting/laying and the plugging in?

Comment: It was tilted on a dolly to move but never laid on it's side. Was not plugged in until a few days after moving into position.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the thermostat switch. They fail when they age and can be replaced. They have a bimetal plate in there and sense the temperature with a long tiny pipe which transfers the temperature from the cooling elements. Normally there are two for each area of the fridge.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- Does the outlet always have power? If connected to a light switch, that could be a problem.
- Is the refrigerator level?
- Does it have an ice-maker or water cooler, that could be causing an issue (e.g. overflowing and/or freezing)?
- Are there separate temperature controls for freezer and refrigerator that need to be set?
- Is there airflow around the condenser coils?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, it always has power when plugged in. Yes, it is level. Yes, it does have an ice-maker but it does not seem to be causing any problem. The controls are set and I have made sure there is airflow.